# How to use if object in list like python in JS

Tags: javascript

In python you can check whether an object is in list or not by doing:

```py
cars = ["bmw","nissan","toyota"]
car = "bmw"

if car in cars:
    print(car)
```

in this case, this will print

```py
bmw
```

which means True, I was wondering how i can do such in JavaScript?

Comment: Something like `cars.find(x => x === car)`?

Comment: what i am trying to is

Comment: let new_btn_enable = ["btn-save-cost-center","btn-cancel-cost-center","btn-return-cost-center"]

let new_btn = document.getElementById("btn-new-cost-center").addEventListener("click", function new_btn() {
    let buttons_container = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons-container")[0].querySelectorAll("*");
    buttons_container.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element instanceof(buttons_container));
        
        if (element.id in new_btn_enable){
            element.disabled = false
        } else {
            element.disabled = true
        }
    
    });
})

Comment: in the if statment i want to know if element.id is in new_btn_enable

Comment: You might want to start the question with that code next time?

Comment: yeah sure sorry man.